# how to run asp.net core develop file in iis server

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a aspnetcore webapi application,i want run it in iis(not vs iis),and dont publish the app,just in use the develop file like:
[app develop file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1frkN.png)

because i dont want publish my app into iis every time I change code

I don't want to see the swagger page only I start vs

I set the iis site path to app develop folder but I get the error code:403.14
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE80r.png)

Comment: Have you find yore answer? marking answer also build your reputation

Answer (score 0):

Check [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS#RunningIISasaDevelopmentServer-no)

> There should be very few reasons for you to run IIS during
> development. Yes, in the past there were very good reasons to run full
> IIS because there were always a number of things that behaved very
> differently in full IIS compared to IIS Express.
>
> However, with ASP.NET
> Core there's little to no reason to be running full IIS during
> development.

You could use dotnet-cli to run your api

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fight the fight that is doomed to fail,

https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Visual Studio uses a trick, which I documented with full detail in the blog post, to run ASP.NET Core apps on IIS/IIS Express. So you only options are,

- Use Visual Studio.
- Publish the app and then run it on IIS.

There is no obvious third option.